# Exercise in differential geometry using Gauss-Bonnet

Tags: differential-geometry

For a positive real number $r$ let $M_{r}$ be the regular surface

$M_{r}=\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2+y^2=z<r^2, x>0,y>0\}$.

Let $K$ denote the Gaussian curvature of $M_{r}$. Determine

$\int_{M_{r}}KdA$ and $\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty}\int_{M_{r}}KdA$.

Solution;
Using Gauss-Bonnet we know $\int_{M_{r}}KdA=\frac{\pi}{2}$, since the surface is the positive quadrant of a paraboloid.

But how does one solve the limit?

Comment: If the sequence is constant, isn't the limit trivial?

Comment: @PinkPanther geometrically it should be something like an infinite paraboloid I suppose..but I dont know how to think about its edges.

Comment: That's not the question. You want to find $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}x_r$, where $x_r$ is constant, so the limit is the same constant

Comment: Your use of Gauss-Bonnet is wrong here. Your justification was quite glib, so I can't tell you exactly how you've gone wrong, but remember that it applies to compact surfaces without boundary.

Comment: @Rhys What does it mean for a compact surface not to have a boundary? if it is is compact then it is closed i.e the boundary belongs to the set.

Comment: There are sort of two related comments here... one is that $M$, as defined, is not compact because it does not include the boundary at $z=r$. The other is to say that including the boundary at $z=r$ (i.e. changing the inequality to equality) does not change the value of the integral, but gives a compact surface with boundary. You can look up the technical definition of a boundary, but it is what you intuitively think of.

Comment: @Rhys so you are saying that one has to mention that we calcluate the latter but that this is the same as the former?

Comment: I'm saying that Gauss-Bonnet doesn't apply here!

Comment: @Rhys: there is a version of Gauss-Bonnet which works on compact surfaces with boundary.  It has extra terms involving the curvature of the boundary curve(s).

Comment: You haven't defined a surface.

Comment: @uniquesolution oh, how is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a complement to the other answer here is a solution that uses [Gauss-Bonnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem):

Let $S_{r}=\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2+y^2=z\leq r^2\}$. By symmetry $\int_{M_{r}}K\;dA=\frac 14\int_{S_{r}}K\;dA$.
Since $S_{r}$ is a compact two-dimensional Riemannian manifold by Gauss-Bonnet

$$\int_{S_{r}} K\;dA+\int_{\partial S_{r}}k_g\;ds=2\pi\chi(S_{r})$$

As $S_{r}$ is homeomorphic to a disc, $\chi(S_{r})=1$. The boundary $\partial S_{r}$ can be parametrized by the curve $\gamma(t)= (r\cos t,r\sin t,r^2)$. 
The unit tangent vector is $T=(-\sin t,\cos t,0)$ and the inward-pointing unit normal  to the boundary $\partial S_{r}$ on the surface $S_r$ at $\gamma(t)$ is $N=\frac {-1}{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}(\cos t,\sin t,2r)$.

Hence
$$\int_{\partial S_{r}}k_g\;ds=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\langle T',N\rangle \,dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac 1{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}\,dt=\frac {2\pi}{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}$$

which implies

$$\int_{S_{r}} K\;dA=2\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}\right)\;,\;\text{so}\;\int_{M_{r}}K\;dA=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}\right)$$

Comment: How come I get the wrong answer applying the formula$\int_{M}KdA=2\pi \chi(M)$?

Comment: i.e why does the integral of the geodesic curvature enter the equation? I have a theorem stating that for compact $M$ the formula in the other comment holds.

Comment: Then your formula is probably stated only for compact 2-dimensional surfaces without boundary. $M_r$ has no boundary but you cannot apply Gauss-Bonnet since it is not compact. $S_r$ however is compact with boundary and the geodesic curvature at  each point of the boundary is $1/(r\cdot\sqrt{1+4r^2})$.

Comment: but how do we compare $M_{r}$ and $S_{r}$ in that case? Then they are not the same set?

Comment: You can write $S_r$ as the disjoint union of $4$ sets isometric to $M_r$ (corresponding to the $4$ open quadrants) and a measure zero set . As curvature is invariant under isometries the integral of the curvature over $S_r$ is $4$ times the integral of the curvature over $M_r$.

Comment: My geodesic curvature is defined as $k_{g}(s)=<T^{'},N \times T>$, isnt it supposed to be that?

Comment: Yes, (up to sign) it's that if you start with an parametrization of the boundary by **arclength** and $N$ is the Gauss map (for some chosen orientation). Actually i call $N$ what you would call $N\times T$ if the orientation is chosen  correctly. If you don't use an arclength parametrization then you have to divide by the the speed of the parametrizing curve (which here is r ) to get the geodesic curvature. If you then integrate the geodesic curvature using that parametrization you have to multiply by the speed again so it cancells out.

Comment: So I can give better answers in future, can you tell me why you accepted an answer that has as much computational complexity as mine but also relies on a fairly heavy theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Just calculate: from Wikipedia (and many other places) we can find the Gaussian curvature of a surface expressed as the graph of a function $z(x,y)$:
$$
K = \frac{z_{xx} z_{yy} - z_{xy}^2}{(1+z_x^2+z_y^2)^2}
$$
where subscripts denote partial derivatives. So we just need to integrate this over the given surface.

Cylindrical coordinates are natural here, so let $x = R\cos(\theta), y=R\sin(\theta)$, and use coordinates $R,\theta$ on $M_r$. The Gaussian curvature is
$$
K = \frac{4}{(1+4R^2)^2}
$$
and the metric on $M_r$ becomes:
$$
ds^2 = dR^2 + R^2d\theta^2 + dz^2 = (1+4R^2)dR^2 + R^2d\theta^2
$$
where we have used the equation of the surface in the last step. Hence the volume form is $R(1+4R^2)^{\frac 12}d\theta dR$.

So the final expression to evaluate is (bearing in mind that we only integrate over $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$ because this corresponds to $x, y > 0$):
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\!\!\!\!d\theta\int_0^r\!\!\!\!dR ~4R(1+4R^2)^{-\frac 32}
$$
Integrate this however you like to get the answer:
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}\right)
$$

The limit as $r\rightarrow\infty$ is then just $\pi/2$.

Comment: My mistake, I missed that. Thank you