# How to calculate $\int_{\Sigma_r}KdA$ of a given surface (Gauss-Bonnet)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I'm working on the following exercise:

> For $r\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ let the surface $\Sigma_{r}$ be given by
> \begin{align}
> \Sigma_r = \left \{  (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}\colon z=\cos \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, x^2+y^2<r^2, x>0,y>0 \right \}
> \end{align}
> Determine the value of the integral
> \begin{align}
> \int_{\Sigma_r}KdA,
> \end{align}
> where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature of $\Sigma_r$.

Perhaps I have to use the fact that:
\begin{align}
\int \kappa_g(s)ds = 2\pi - \int_{\Sigma_r}KdA 
\end{align}

Where $\kappa(s)= \left \langle \dot{T}(s),N(s)  \right \rangle
$. Or maybe
\begin{align}
\int_{\Sigma_r}KdA = 2\pi \cdot \chi(\Sigma_r) 
\end{align}

I'm trying to find this expressions although I can't find the parameterization yet. ¿Is this surface homeomorphic to an easier one? Should I try finding $K$? How can I apply the theorem if I really don't know if the surface is compact? I am guided by this question: [Exercise in differential geometry using Gauss-Bonnet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315068/exercise-in-differential-geometry-using-gauss-bonnet?rq=1)

I am a bit lost and would appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Gauss-Bonnet theorem ?

Comment: @MathiasRousset Yes, I'm supposed to use it but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: Start by writing down the statement of the theorem and figuring out what every single symbol means.

Comment: What is the meaning of $N$ here? This is a rather *non-standard* notation. It is neither the principal normal of the curve nor the surface normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameterization is already given in $\Sigma_r,$ it's a graph of the function $z(x,y).$ While let $x=R\cos(\theta),$ $y=R\sin(\theta),$ $z=\cos(R).$ So you can directly compute Gaussian curvature like the answer linked in your question(unaccpeted one).

Or the other way is to use Gauss-Bonnet Thm, which is the accpeted answer in the linked question. As surface $\Sigma_r$ is a graph of the function $z(x,y)$ on a quarter disk with radius $r,$ it's homeomorphic to the quarter disk, and of course disk. So $\chi(\Sigma_r)=1.$ Actually your $\Sigma_r$ is really not compact, but the boundary has no contribution to the integral $\int K dA$. So consider $\overline{\Sigma}_r$ instead, which is a compact one.

If you decide to use Gauss-Bonnet Thm, use symmetry first like the accpeted answer in your link.